# Can I use FOR ALL ENTRIES with GROUP BY?

Tags: performance, abap, opensql

Currently the code looks something like this:

```
LOOP AT lt_orders ASSIGNING <fs_order>.
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM order_items
      INTO <fs_order>-cnt
      WHERE order_id = <fs_order>-order_id.
ENDLOOP.
```

It is the slowest part of the report. I want to speed it up.

How can I use FOR ALL ENTRIES with GROUP BY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Not directly, only through a CDS view

While all of the answers provide a faster solution than the one in the question, the fastest way is not mentioned.

If you have at least Netweaver 7.4, EHP 5 (and you should, it was released in 2014), you can use CDS views, even if you are not on HANA.

It still cannot be done directly, as OpenSQL does not allow FOR ALL ENTRIES with GROUP BY, and CDS views cannot handle FOR ALL ENTRIES. However, you can create one of each.

CDS:

```sql
    @AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'zorder_i_fae'
    DEFINE VIEW zorder_items_fae AS SELECT FROM order_items {
      order_id,
      count( * ) AS cnt, 
    }
    GROUP BY order_id
```

OpenSQL:

```sql
    SELECT * 
        FROM zorder_items_fae
        INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_order_cnt)
        FOR ALL ENTRIES IN @lt_orders
        WHERE order_id = @lt_orders-order_id.
```

### Speed

If `lt_orders` contains more than about 30% of all possible `order_id` values from table `ORDER_ITEMS`, the [answer from iPirat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52653955/2354702) is faster. (While using more memory, obviously)

However, if you need only a couple hunderd `order_id` values out of millions, this solution is about 10 times faster than any other answer, and 100 times faster than the original.

Answer (score 1):

[Check the documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abenwhere_logexp_itab.htm). You can't use `GROUP BY`. Maybe in this case, you could try selecting your items with FAE outside of the loop, then count them using a [parallel cursor](http://zevolving.com/2009/12/parallel-cursor-to-speed-up-performance-of-nested-loop/):

```
REPORT.

TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_result,
         vbeln TYPE vbeln,
         cnt   TYPE i.
TYPES: END OF ty_result.

DATA: lt_headers TYPE SORTED TABLE OF ty_result WITH UNIQUE KEY vbeln,
      lv_tabix   TYPE sy-tabix VALUE 1.

"get the headers
SELECT vbeln FROM vbak UP TO 100 ROWS INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_headers.

"get corresponding items
SELECT vbeln, posnr FROM vbap FOR ALL ENTRIES IN @lt_headers
  WHERE vbeln EQ @lt_headers-vbeln 
  ORDER BY vbeln, posnr 
  INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_items).


LOOP AT lt_headers ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<h>).
  LOOP AT lt_items FROM lv_tabix ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<i>).

    IF <i>-vbeln NE <h>-vbeln.
      lv_tabix = sy-tabix.
      EXIT.
    ELSE.
      <h>-cnt = <h>-cnt + 1.
    ENDIF.

  ENDLOOP.
ENDLOOP.

BREAK-POINT.
```

Or join header/item with a distinct count on the item id (whichever column that would be in your table).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like

```
  SELECT COUNT(order_item_id) AS cnt, order_id 
  FROM order_items
  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_count
  GROUP BY order_id.
```

Assuming that `order_item_id` is a key in the `order_items` table. And assuming that `lt_count` has two fields: `cnt` of type `int8` and `order_id` of same type as your other `order_id` fields

PS: then you can loop over `lt_count` and move the counts to `lt_orders`. Or the other way around. To speed up the loop, sort one of the tables and use `READ ... BINARY SEARCH`

Comment: Why not define `lt_count` as SORTED?

Comment: Yea, sure, you could also use `order by` in the select statement and let the DB sort. Both are *further* performance improvements to your problem. Not using a select in a loop is your *main* problem.

Answer (score 1):

I did with table KNB1 (customer master in company code), where we have customers, which are created in several company codes.

Please note, because of FOR ALL ENTRIES you have to SELECT the full key.

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_knb1,
         kunnr TYPE knb1-kunnr,
         count TYPE i,
       END OF ty_knb1.

TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_knb1_fae,
         kunnr TYPE knb1-kunnr,
       END OF ty_knb1_fae.

DATA: lt_knb1_fae TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_knb1_fae.
DATA: lt_knb1 TYPE HASHED TABLE OF ty_knb1
                   WITH UNIQUE KEY kunnr.
DATA: ls_knb1 TYPE ty_knb1.
DATA: ls_knb1_db TYPE knb1.

START-OF-SELECTION.

  lt_knb1_fae = VALUE #( ( kunnr = ... ) ). "add at least one customer which is created in several company codes

  ls_knb1-count = 1.
  SELECT kunnr bukrs
         INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF ls_knb1_db
         FROM knb1
         FOR ALL ENTRIES IN lt_knb1_fae
         WHERE kunnr EQ lt_knb1_fae-kunnr.
    ls_knb1-kunnr = ls_knb1_db-kunnr.
    COLLECT ls_knb1 INTO lt_knb1.
  ENDSELECT.
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a range table for your `lt_orders`, like `lt_orders_range`.
2. Do `select order_id, count( * ) where order_id in lt_orders_range`.

If you think this is too much to create a range table, you will save a lot of performance by running just one select for all orders instead of single select for each order id.